# Where can I get the latest FluentNHibernate build?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my applications, I've used FluentNHibernate quite a lot. Unfortunately, [a Visual Studio Bug has forced me to get a different FNH version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331325/what-causes-the-vs-2010-sp1-wpf-designer-to-crash), but ever since the project homepage has switched to GitHub, there is no working download link for compiled binaries anymore, so it's impossible to get a signed, strong-named version at this point.

What I've done is get the source and build my own version (using VS, not rake / albacore), which has - lacking the original .snk - no strong name / another strong name than the original. This creates some incompatibility between my assemblies, which in part use the vendor build and in part my own.

So, how the hell do you guys / gals deal with this issue? I can't be the only one looking for the latest FNH binaries, can I? Is there some continuous integration platform hosting it?

EDIT : The current source code also contains the SNK, so I can sign it like the original build and won't have any more trouble. Still, it would be great if there was a CI build available online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nuget ? 
http://nuget.org/packages/FluentNHibernate

Comment: Thanks for this, but we've been experiencing some critical issues working with nuget in connection with other dependencies. Furthermore, we don't want to integrate Nuget in our CI environment. Is there some way to just download the dll from nuget?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrating NuGet in CI environment"? NuGet just provides you with dlls you need, these are still physical libraries and build process is not even aware of NuGet.

Comment: Hm. Misconception on my part, then. Just looked into it and saw that NuGet creates a local repository of the dlls. Since we have our own repository (a Team Project in TFS), I can just create a temp project to get the dlls via nuget and copy them. Thanks!

Comment: You can specify version when you install package localy:PM> Install-Package FluentNHibernate -Version 1.3.0.717